# ASP.NET Web Forms Application Suddenly Throwing JavaScript Error

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webforms

For some unknown reason, an ASP.NET Web Forms application that I've been working on for months has suddenly begun throwing this JavaScript error:

> JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method
>   'indexOf'.

This error appears in one of the dynamic, read-only JavaScript files that (I assume) ASP.NET has created. The block of code in which the error is highlighted is this one:

```
_applyWatermark : function() {
        // Apply the watermark to the textbox
        var wrapper = Sys.Extended.UI.TextBoxWrapper.get_Wrapper(this.get_element());
        wrapper.set_Watermark(this._watermarkText);
        wrapper.set_IsWatermarked(true);

        if(!this._watermarkCssClass)
            return;

        var classList = this.get_element().className.split();
        if(classList.indexOf(this._watermarkCssClass) === -1) {
            classList.push(this._watermarkCssClass);
            this.get_element().className = classList.join(" ");
        }
    }
```

The Visual Studio debugger specifically points out this line as the source of the above-mentioned error:

> if(classList.indexOf(this._watermarkCssClass) === -1) {

Using some context clues, I can see that the error appears to have something to do with the `Watermark extenders` that I am using. The `classList` variable apparently isn't being assigned the correct value, but I don't know why this is suddenly happening. This application has never thrown this error before.

Unfortunately, this application is proprietary, so I cannot include the code. Believe me, if I could, I would include the code to get this headache dealt with.

I should add that this error occurs on page load on every page that includes a `Watermark extender`.

If this question is insufficiently descriptive, or if it belongs somewhere else, please let me know. I really have no clue what's going on. Thanks for any help.

Comment: I commented out the Watermark extenders and the app ran with no errors. Interesting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon further investigation, I have found that the `<meta>` tags in some of my Master Pages are causing the problem. The `content` attribute should be set to `IE=edge`. This is how it should read:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

I'm not entirely sure why this suddenly caused the app to break, but it seems to have fixed the problem. I hope this helps someone later on.